# Could not set value to the list view using holder

Tags: android, listview

when I am trying to set values to the list view using custom adapter it didn't display the data from hash map. values that I want to display in the list view is getting from the database.and my list view contains text views and edit texts.
my code is

```
    private void SelectItems() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {

           datas = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("select distinct im_code ,im_desc ,im_srp "
                + " from itemmaster", null);

        Log.v("item detailss", c.toString());

            while (c.moveToNext()){

            HashMap<String, String> datanums = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String im_code = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("im_code"));

             String desc = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("im_desc"));

             datanums.put("codec", im_code);
             datanums.put("namec", desc);


       String price = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("im_srp"));
            datanums.put("imsrpc", price);


            }
        } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
           } 

}

private void ViewItems() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    list.setAdapter(null);
     arrTemp = new String[datas.size()];
     datas.add(datanums);

     MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter();
    list.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
    Log.v("list itemm",datas.toString());
    }

private class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(datas != null && datas.size() != 0){
            return datas.size();    
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return datas.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //ViewHolder holder = null;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = Orders.this.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_simple_row, null);
            holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.srp);
            holder.textview3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
            holder.editText1 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cases);    
            holder.editText2 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pcs); 


            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.ref = position;

        holder.textView1.setText(datanums.get("namec"));
        holder.textView2.setText(datanums.get("imsrpc"));
        holder.textview3.setText(datanums.get("codec"));
        holder.editText1.setText(arrTemp[position]);
        holder.editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                arrTemp[holder.ref] = arg0.toString();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {

        TextView textView1,textView2,textview3;
        EditText editText1,editText2;
        int ref;
    }

}
```

in this viewitems(), and selectitems(), are methods called from oncreate to retrieve and display value in the list view. I couldn't sort out the exact problem.but the edit texts are showing properly in the output.please help.

Comment: Try to change `private class ViewHolder` to `static class ViewHolder`. And all variables in `ViewHolder` class should be `public`

Comment: when i am making it to static even my edit texts are not displaying.what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add below line at start of the getView method

```
HashMap<String, String> datanums=datas.get(possition);
```

Comment: I used this.Still no datas retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public List<Map<String, String>> SelectItems() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try {

       datas = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
    newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("select distinct im_code ,im_desc ,im_srp "
            + " from itemmaster", null);

    Log.v("item detailss", c.toString());

        while (c.moveToNext()){

        HashMap<String, String> datanums = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String im_code = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("im_code"));

         String desc = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("im_desc"));

         datanums.put("codec", im_code);
         datanums.put("namec", desc);


   String price = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("im_srp"));
        datanums.put("imsrpc", price);


        }
    } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
       } 


return datas;

}
```

/* In your Activity or adapter class call this method(this will return the list) and check the condition if( arraylist!=null && arraylist.size()>0) */

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to set your text view. Hope this works.

```
holder.textView1.setText(datas.get(position).get("namec"));
holder.textview3.setText(datas.get(position).get("codec"));
holder.textview3.setText(datas.get(position).get("srpc"));
```